# Change the size of a help window to fit the text

Tags: c++, qt

I want to change the size of the help window to fit the size of the text, but don't know how to proceed.

Here is my code :

```
QTextEdit *help = new QTextEdit(this);
help->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window); 
help->setReadOnly(true);
////
QFile file(":/help.txt");
QTextStream stream ( &file );
QString line;

if (!file.open (QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    //some error report
}

while( !stream.atEnd() ) {
    line = stream.readLine();
    help->append(line);
}
file.close(); 

help->show();
```

Comment: How does it show? It displays something or it doesn't display at all?

Comment: it shows a small window, i want to adjust or resize it

Comment: like @IceFire said you should first decide about the width of the text and then to compute its height. After you get the full width of the text you must find on how many rows will the text display for a fixed width: rows = textWidth/desiredWidth, then to get the adjusted height you must to something like: adjustedHeight = rows * textHeight. After that you set the layout width and height of your window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some layout information about your text because, in theory, it could be rendered in one really, really long line.

So, I would aim for some target width of the text while all text being wider than that will be wrapped. Now, what you need is the height for that kind of text.

My suggestion would be that you use a `QTextDocument`, set the width as described above, insert all the text and get the size using `QTextDocument::size`. That way, you get the measures and can resize your window to those (adding margin, padding etc., of course).